# Block a specific timeframe when adding new entries to a Modern SharePoint Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, sharepoint-calendar, modern-pages

I am trying to block the timeframe 11AM-12PM so users won't be able to select it when adding new entries to a modern SharePoint calendar. I can't find anything online that can point me in the right direction, and I am wondering if it's even possible to do.

The only way I can think of getting this done is through a workflow, where the user will receive an email to resubmit their entry outside of that timeframe and then delete the current entry. I am hoping there is a better approach to this.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution myself by playing with some of the SP validation formulas and more specifically the OR function.

Here are the exact formulas that worked for my scenario. I hope someone finds this useful:

```
=OR(TIME(11,0,0)>TIME(HOUR(StartTime),MINUTE(StartTime),SECOND(StartTime)),TIME(11,59,0)<TIME(HOUR(StartTime),MINUTE(StartTime),SECOND(StartTime)))
```

..for the Start Time field validation. And:

```
=OR(TIME(11,0,0)>TIME(HOUR(EndTime),MINUTE(EndTime),SECOND(EndTime)),TIME(11,59,0)<TIME(HOUR(EndTime),MINUTE(EndTime),SECOND(EndTime)))
```

..for the end Time field validation.

Note: I made the default Start Time and End Time columns Hidden, and created 2 new ones, as the validation textbox wasn't available for the default fields.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing, you could mark you reply as answer which will help others meet the similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can block the built in timeframe 11AM-12PM with OOB way.

In addition, in sharepoint online, we suggest you use [flow](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-flow-for-a-list-or-library-in-sharepoint-or-onedrive-a9c3e03b-0654-46af-a254-20252e580d01) to remind user re-submit the event since the workflow has been deprecated.

Comment: There was an OOB way actually. It just took a bit of trial and error :) I will share it in a bit. As far as using flows, I wish I could use them, but that's not an option for my organization at the moment.